# Can $z^3+1$ be powerful for integer $z$ other than $-1,0,2$ and $23$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, powerful-numbers

In 1976, Schinzel and Tijdeman proved that if a polynomial $P(z)$ with integer coefficients has at least $3$ simple zeros, then there may be at most finitely many $z$ such that $P(z)$ is a perfect power. They further conjectured that, under the same condition on $P$, there may be at most finitely many $z$ such that $P(z)$ is a powerful number. Recall that an integer $n$ is powerful if prime $p$ divides $n$ implies that $p^2$ divides $n$. Equivalently, powerful numbers are numbers of the form $x^3y^2$ for integers $x,y$.

My first question: is there any polynomial $P(z)$ for which this conjecture is proved? If not, are there any partial results, other than computer search for small $z$ and the full proof conditional on the abc conjecture?

The simplest polynomial $P(z)$ with $3$ simple zeros is $z^3+1$. It is easy to check that $(-1)^3+1=0$, $0^3+1=1$,  $2^3+1=3^2$ and $23^3+1 = 2^3 3^2 13^2$, but is this all? In this case, the problem reduces to the equation $x^3y^2=z^3+1$, or $(-z)^3-y^2(-x)^3=1$. Equation $x^3-dy^3=1$ is the famous Skolem's equation, for which there is a rich theory. Can this theory be used to prove that this equation has no integer solutions other than $(1,0)$ if $d$ is a perfect square other than $d=0,1,9,$ and $39^2$?

[1] A. Schinzel and R. Tijdeman. On the equation $y^m = P(x)$. Acta Arith., 31(2):199–204, 1976.

Comment: What is known about $\ x^3\cdot y^2-u^2\cdot z^3=1\,$?

Comment: Equation $x^3y^2-u^2z^3=1$ has infinitely many solutions. Take, for example, $x=1$, $z=2$, and solve Pell's equation $y^2-8u^2=1$.

Comment: Thank you (dziękuję).

Comment: How far past $23$ have you looked?

Comment: Up to $20$ millions in $|z|$

Comment: For a fixed $x$, the equation $$(x^3y)^2 = (xz)^3 + x^3$$ represents a [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve), solutions to which are [readily available](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~bennett/BeGa-data.html) at least for all $|x^3|<10^7$.

Comment: Thanks. I checked for $|x|$ up to some bound $B$ (but do not remember $B$) using Magma - no new solutions. In fact, heuristics suggest that large solutions are unlikely, so the question is how to prove that there are no more solutions.